# Migrating SVN to Git: cannot create a case-sensitve disk image

Tags: git, svn, case-sensitive

I am following the [tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-prepare) on atlassian.com how to migrate from SVN to Git on Windows 10 Enterprise and need to mount a case-sensitive disk image.

The command `svn-migration-scripts.jar create-disk-image 5 GitMigration` returns the following error:

> Unrecognised or missing command Available commands:
>
> - authors
> - bitbucket-push
> - clean-git
> - sync-rebase
> - verify

The command svn-migration-scripts.jar verify returned

> svn-migration-ssvn-migration-scripts: using version 0.1.56bbc7f Git:
> using version 2.28.0.windows.1 Subversion: using version 1.9.4
> git-svn: using version 2.28.0.windows.1 You appear to be running on a
> case-insensitive file-system. This is unsupported, and can result in
> data loss. Cannot connect directly to internet. This may interfere
> with your ability to clone Subversion repositories and push Git
> repositories.ripts.jar

Comment: The library you are using does not appear to support Windows (since windows uses case-insensitive file systems). Use a different tool or operating system. From [the tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-prepare): "Disclaimer: for the svn migration you need a case-sensitive filesystem and this does not work on NTFS. We suggest using this on a Linux machine."

Comment: Sorry, I should have added more details. The tutorial provides me with a tool - the file svn-migration-scripts.jar. In this file there is supposed to be the command create-disk-image which will create a case-sensitive disk image under Windows where I can work. This command is not found (see error message), but the class exists in the jar, so the error must be due to something else.

Comment: According to the same page I linked previously, that command is meant for OSX and not Windows. If you're on Windows and do not have access to a computer running Linux (virtual or otherwise) your best options is probably to use WSL and some Linux dist.

Comment: Ah, ok. Great, thanks for your answer. Now I have to mark your answer as correct and close the question... At the moment I do not see how to do this.

Comment: @Eve fredrik didn't post an answer and instead posted a comment. It has to be posted as an answer to be marked as correct. However, you can upvote the comment (don't know if you need sufficient reputation for this).

Answer (score 3):

The `create-disk-image` command is only available under OS X. (Source: https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/svn-migration-scripts/issues/1/case-insensitive-warning-on-windows-ntfs)

However, under Win 10 you can create a case-sensitive directory with `fsutil.exe`. In the PowerShell execute the following command (replace `<directory>` with the actual directory path):

```
fsutil.exe file SetCaseSensitiveInfo <directory> enable
```

(if you get an error see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60448790/2294031)

Afterwards `svn-migration-scripts.jar verfiy` won't complain about a case-insensitive file-system.